# Openlayers: Read GPX file and process every trackpoint

Tags: openlayers-3, gpx

I am loading a GPX file with a track and showing it in a Vector layer, no problem:

```
new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/examples/data/gpx/fells_loop.gpx',
    format: new ol.format.GPX()
})
```

But I would also like to access the coordinates and timestamp of every trackpoint in order to calculate speed and heading along the track. I cannot find a way to hook into Openlayers in order to access this information. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think u should work with features that u get in ur vector source